# Quickly finding an object in an array

Tags: lua

For a collision detection game, I was thinking about splitting objects in my environment between different chunks to decrease the number of objects it needs to check to only those in the same (and neighboring) chunks. However some of my objects (bullets) will be quickly passing through different chunks and so I need to quickly move those objects from one array to another.

I was thinking about using a dictionary instead of an array so I can use a unique key as an index to quickly find the bullet and move it, but I decided to see if anyone here might know of a better way?

I plan on having a few thousand objects in my game (including bullets), the objects themselves will only be circles and rectangles with bullets being represented as a line segment.

Comment: When calculating collision between a fast bullet and an object, represent the bullet as a line segment from its previous frame's position to its current position.  So, you will find the collision independently of the bullet speed.

Comment: Just for clarification, I think I understand what you mean by the term "chunk," but be careful using that when talking about Lua because it has a particular meaning. (See [this page](https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_load) if you are interested.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "chunk" you mean different areas within the game world that operate more-or-less independently from one another to reduce overhead. If I am wrong about this, please correct me.

As for the question of bullet trajectory between "chunks," I would recommend recording a bullet's point of origin--that is, the point where it was fired--and the point where it collided with an object. This could be achieved with some sort of collision detection that relies on your game world's coordinate system, whatever that happens to be. I would recommend creating a `Bullet` class. This is a quick proof-of-concept I came up with that can be loaded as a module with `require`:

```
local Bullet = {__type = "Bullet"}

-- This function could take bullet information as parameters, such as its point of origin
-- and calibre.
function Bullet.new(start_pos_in, calibre_in)
    -- Record start and ending positions in this table, probably represented by some 
    -- (x, y) coordinate pairs, assuming your game is 2D. I just used a generic 
    -- placeholder here called 'Point'.
    local self = {
        calibre = calbibre_in,
        start_pos = start_pos_in
        end_pos = Point.new(0, 0)
    }
    local mt = {
        __metatable = "metatable",
        __newindex = function(t, k, v)
            local e = string.format("type Bullet has no member '%s'", k)
            return error(e, 2)
        end,
        __index = self
    }
    return setmetatable(self, mt)
end

return Bullet
```

Using my above example, a `Bullet` object can be instantiated like this:

```
-- Using .50 calibre as an example.
-- 'x' and 'y' represent the bullet's point of origin in the game world.
local bullet = Bullet.new(Point.new(x, y), ".50")
```

Once a `Bullet` object has collided with something in the game world, you can record its point of impact using the internal variable `end_pos`, calculate its distance traveled, and so forth. Depending on how your "chunk" system will work, you can record the bullet's "chunk" of origin as well.

Just as a side note, I would recommend trying to implement object pooling for your bullet particles to save on overhead. (See [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/847-object-pooling-in-unity) for reference if you are interested.)